# Shift a string and Find Number of indices that matches between each shift of strings

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

Having trouble trying to calculate the number of matches between 2 strings:

Firstly, I need to shift a string from numbers 1 to 5 and calculate the number of matches between each shifts, if the # of matches is greater than before then remember that shift # otherwise use the previous one. A match would be based on if a character of an index in the previous string matches the character of the same index in the string after

```
original string: ABCDZZ
shift 1:          ABCDZ  match = 1 (index 4,"ABCDZ" is the new string, original shifted by 1)
shift 2:           ABCD  match = 0 ("ABCD" is the new string, original shifted by 2)
shift 3:            ABC  match = 0 ("ABC" is the new string, original shifted by 3)
shift 4:             AB  match = 0 ("AB" is the new string, original shifted by 4)
shift 5:              A  """
```

So my output would be shift 1, since that had the greatest # of matches.
Doing it manually is fairly simple but I am having trouble doing this with for loops. Mainly how to get the for loop to iterate comparing the index of each new string? Is that more effective or would it make sense to slice the string based on the number of shifts? If anyone could help with even just the pseudocode for this, I'm not sure my logic is right when I am doing it. Is there any way to figuratively create two rows and compare it that way, because the indexs of each string won't even line up unless I put a space in the front as a placeholder everytime I shift.

Edit:
I was thinking of splitting the string into a list of characters and then comparing the index to the "new" string which would be the list[:-1] and list[0,"] essentially creating a place holder as the spaces in the shift and then -1 for the last characters removal. But going forward, I have to use the "new" string, so I'm not sure how to keep those current changes while still using variables in a for loop. The string is much smaller to the one I actually need to find the matches for, thus it is unknown what the letters actually are. I just need to find a way to compare the indexs of the previous strings to the index of the shifted one.

Comment: *I'm not sure my logic is right when I am doing it*. That's fine, but please show the logic you are using and explain why do you think it is not working as expected and where it fails.

Comment: I was thinking of splitting the string into a list of characters and then comparing the index to the "new" string which would be the list[:-1] and list[0,"] essentially creating a place holder as the spaces in the shift and then -1 for the last characters removal. But going forward, I have to use the "new" string, so I'm not sure how to keep those current changes while still using variables in a for loop.

Comment: Great. If you edit the question and add this explanation (if you have some code,even better) others will understand your question way better and can help you more efficiently.

Comment: I think each character is a match only if it is equal to its previous character in the string. So at each step you only need to find consequent similar characters.

Comment: `z` is a match only because it is the same as the previous character. Same logic can be applied throughout